# Quick Access Toolbar Customization: Selecting Macros causes Excel to crash

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, crash

Running Office '10 on Win7
Experience: Some VBA experience, no XML experience

Hi,
I have two issues and an answer to the first may render the second mute.

Q1) Is there a way to get macros in locked add-ins to show up in the QAT macros drop-down? For example, I am running Hyperion and the essexleqd.xla and essexcln.xll add-ins are running. At least some of the macros for these add-ins are visible in the QAT macros drop-down, even though the add-in itself is locked.

Q2) Situation: Excel application is open, but there is no active/visible sheet open. When I go to customize QAT and then select macros from the drop-down, I get an error message and Excel crashes then restarts. Has anyone else encountered this, or know why this happens and has a fix?

Background:
I have a simple add-in that I want to distribute. I have locked it for viewing, but this means that I cannot create a QAT button that references the macro because the macro from the add-in is not visible in the QAT macros drop-down. I have read here (http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut03.htm) that this happens, but that I should be able to write in the name of the macro somewhere and the button will work.

Answer (score 3):

Q1)

This article should help you.

[How to: Create a Custom Menu That Calls a Macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508923.aspx)

Q2)

I would guess that they crash because they can't handle that there is no active worksheet open.  You probably have to start Excel by opening an empty file in order to workaround the issue.

Comment: In regards to Q2, I was having a similar issue; Excel crashed everytime I tried to add a macro to the QAT without an open workbook (just an open instance of Excel). Turns out you were right; I needed to have an open workbook too. +1 for alerting me to the workaround.

Comment: Opening a blank sheet fixed the issue for me. Brilliant!